# Is there a way to override require_once of the main theme on the child theme?

Tags: customization, themes, child-theme

I would like to override a `require_once` present at the beginning of the functions.php of my main theme through my child theme.

specifically I have:

```
require_once get_template_directory().'/libs/some-function.php
```

I know that replacing `get_template_directory()` with `get_stylesheet_directory()` I can load a modified copy of the some-function.php file into my child theme. but I wouldn't  change the parent theme, I would make the change only in the child theme.

I add that the `require_once` is not hooked

Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: See my answer to a similar question here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296775/are-custom-inner-theme-folders-in-any-way-overridable-by-child-themes/296845#296845

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the parent themes `functions.php` is always loaded, and `require_once` is not a WordPress API but a part of the PHP language itself

The only way to change it would be to modify the file