# Inheritance of parent theme plugin files in a child theme

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, template-hierarchy

I have parent theme that has some plugins in it, those plugins are added as a dependency.

In the child theme, I want to override some of the files that belong to those plugins, but it looks like that isn't working.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are custom inner theme folders in any way overridable by child themes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296775/are-custom-inner-theme-folders-in-any-way-overridable-by-child-themes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have parent theme that has some plugins in it, those plugins are added as a dependency.

You shouldn't be bundling plugins in themes

> In the child theme, I want to override some of the files that belong to those plugins, but it looks like that isn't working.

Child themes let you override templates, these are not templates, and use `require`/`include` to load.

> Is this possible at all?

**No**

Modifying plugins involves either forking them or extending them via actions and filters. As a result, replacing a plugin file in the way you propose is bad practice. Doing it via a child theme is even worse, but luckily that is not possible.

Use actions/hooks/filters instead