# Override file inside inc in child theme

Tags: child-theme, include

I want to make a child theme of hesita. This theme has templates in the inc/sections folder and I would like to load these from my child theme instead of from the main theme.

Tried to copy the files over, but it doesn't seem to work. It's still loading the parent themes inc/section file.

Is it possible to make WP read the inc file from my child theme instead of the parent theme?

Comment: it's "hesita" or the opensource theme "hestia" ? https://wordpress.org/themes/hestia/

Comment: it's the free version, not the pro version. I'm just curious why its not possible to override the theme. I found a hook to fix what I wanted, but still curious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are custom inner theme folders in any way overridable by child themes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296775/are-custom-inner-theme-folders-in-any-way-overridable-by-child-themes)