# How to override the "inc" folder (or any folder) in a theme using child theme?

Tags: themes, templates, child-theme

I am using Storefront theme (But question isn't specify to this theme, I am asking question for any theme).

I can easily override files like header.php, footer.php using child theme(just copy and paste the file).

But I can't override any files which is on "inc" folder (any folder). How can I override those files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are custom inner theme folders in any way overridable by child themes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296775/are-custom-inner-theme-folders-in-any-way-overridable-by-child-themes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WordPress only looks for the default template files while loading the child theme. So does woocommerce.

Any extra folder or file that exists in your parent theme **can not** be overridden, unless the developer is using actions and filters that allows you to hook into them. Therefore, a simple `require()` or `include()` can't be overridden by a child theme.

What you can do is to track the template file that is calling the files from the `inc` folder, and then override those in your theme's folder. You might need to go as back as `functions.php`.

For a complete list of default template files, take a look at the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

Comment: Are you sure about this? I was able to override similar files in some themes.

Comment: What kind of files? Maybe the theme provided support for this, by checking if the file exists in the child-theme folder ( woocommerce does something similar to this )

Answer (score 0):

Certain parent themes use locate_template(), which does allow child themes to override non-default files in the parent theme. It's just something the parent theme has to support.