# Child theme overirde template-tags in a theme built on underscores in inc/template-tags

Tags: php, functions, child-theme, template-tags

I've read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296775/are-custom-inner-theme-folders-in-any-way-overridable-by-child-themes) post and I don't think this question is a duplicate because I have a specific question that has not been answered.

My parent theme is using the following to require a template tag php file

```
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';
```

Is it possible to overide this in my child theme, If I place the same code in my functions.php and place the folder and file the same in my child theme folder I get a error saying

```
 Fatal error: Cannot redeclare progression_studios_category_transient_flusher() (previously declared in /home/anders/Local Sites/site/app/public/wp-content/themes/vayvo-progression-child/inc/template-tags.php:401) in /home/anders/Local Sites/site/app/public/wp-content/themes/vayvo-progression/inc/template-tags.php on line 401
```

Is it possible to work around this.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: You get that error because two functions cannot exist with the same name. There are actions and filters to deal with this issue.

Comment: Ok I will look into what those mean. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are custom inner theme folders in any way overridable by child themes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296775/are-custom-inner-theme-folders-in-any-way-overridable-by-child-themes)

Comment: That is the post I mentioned in my question that I said does not answer my question. Because my use case isn't mentioned.